# jQuery Click Event firing on right click only ~ Magnific Popup ~ Magento

Tags: jquery, magento, popup

**Situation:**
I have a Magnific Popup  on a magento site & it is using ajax but for some reason the close button isn't working!

**Demo:**
Well i cant show you the site as it's under-development and it will take too much time to replicate the issue on fiddle.

**What i have tried:**
Since the default functionality isn't working and after wasting a lot of time, i tried to find my work around by applying a click event on close button to force close the popup:

```
jQuery(document).bind('click', function(e) {

        jQuery("mfp-close").unbind(); //incase any other event is conflicting.

        var lookForCloseBtn = jQuery(e.target);

        if (jQuery(lookForCloseBtn).hasClass("mfp-close")){
            var magnificPopup = jQuery.magnificPopup.instance;
            magnificPopup.close();
        }
});
```

This dosent do the trick but if i **right click the close button, the code works!!** i have no clue what is going on..... how can i make it respond to left click?

Any suggestions are welcome!

---

**Edit:**
I tried binding a random "alert" msg on document click using console while the popu was open ~ click event only triggered when i right clicked any part of popup but the same code will be triggered on left click without the popup!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was an unclosed `<script>` tag, due to which close button went right inside it and this wasn't shown in inspect element option of browsers...